# Replace uppercase to lowercase within htaccess using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following line in my htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^images/9440/(([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2})[^/]*\.jpg)$ /images/9440/img-$2/$1`

This an example of the URL that htaccess rule will apply to: `/images/9440/F121R529.jpg`

The thing is I have changed the name of my images to lowercase. So it went from `F1` to `f1`. How can I modify the my regex expression to convert to lowecase.

thanks

Comment: I came up with the expression, but for some reason I can't get it to work within htaccess
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/weYHGO/1

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/TKBjZm/1) might help you to create a target group and perform a lowercase as you wish:

```
images\/9440\/([A-Z0-9]+)\.jpg
```

[image]